# Python Hollow Diamond Pattern Program Optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have been exploring Python & was making a program to generate a *hollow diamond pattern* like the one shown below:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * *     * * * * * * 
* * * * *         * * * * * 
* * * *             * * * * 
* * *                 * * * 
* *                     * * 
*                         * 
*                         * 
* *                     * * 
* * *                 * * * 
* * * *             * * * * 
* * * * *         * * * * * 
* * * * * *     * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Here is its code. I would like to know what are other better ways to do it with less complexity (meaning less number of loops)

```
n = int(input("Enter Size of Pattern: "))
#Upper Traingles
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    #Top Left Triangle
    for j in range(1, i+1): 
        print("*", end =" ")

    #Space between top triangles
    for j in range(n-i):
        print(" ",end=" ")

    #Top Right Triangle
    for j in range(n, 0, -1):
        if(i < j):
            print(" ",end=" ")
        else:
            print("*", end =" ") 

    print("\n", end="")

#Bottom Triangles    
for i in range(-1, n-1):
    #Bottom Left Triangle
    for j in range(-1, i+1): 
        print("*", end =" ")

    #Space between Bottom Triangles
    for j in range((n-2)-i):
        print(" ",end=" ")

    #Bottom Right Triangle
    for j in range(-1, n-1):
        if(j < (n-3)-i):
            print(" ",end=" ")
        else:
            print("*", end =" ") 

    print("\n", end="")
```

I am new to python so a bit naive question. Help me reduce this code's complexity.

I have also seen few programs but they don't work according to this solution.

Thank you for any helps

Comment: I posted an answer, did you see it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and yes I will try to keep my questions as clean as possible. Also thank you for the edits. Would help me framing my next question easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input("Enter pattern size: "))    

for i in range(n):
    print((n-i) * '* ' + (2*i) * ' ' + (2*i) * ' ' + (n-i) * '* ' )
for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
    print((n-i) * '* ' + (2*i) * ' ' + (2*i) * ' ' + (n-i) * '* ')
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *     * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *         * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * *             * * * * * * *
* * * * * *                 * * * * * *
* * * * *                     * * * * *
* * * *                         * * * *
* * *                             * * *
* *                                 * *
*                                     *
*                                     *
* *                                 * *
* * *                             * * *
* * * *                         * * * *
* * * * *                     * * * * *
* * * * * *                 * * * * * *
* * * * * * *             * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *         * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *     * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n = int(input("enter the number of row:"))
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    for j in range(2*(n-i)):
        print(" ", end=" ")
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print("*", end=" ")

    print()

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    for j in range(2*(n-i-1)):
        print(" ", end=" ")
    for j in range(i+1):
        print("*", end=" ")

    print()
```

output:

```
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * *     * * * *
* * *         * * *
* *             * *
*                 *
*                 *
* *             * *
* * *         * * *
* * * *     * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: a more elegant solution was already provided and accepted

Comment: if someone needs a different solution this answer will be helpful